# Initially apply CSS transform and remove with transition on click?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transform

I have a simple menu hide / unhide mechanism as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_control" />
<label for="menu_control" class="navbar toggle button" />
<div class="menu category foo">
   ...
</div>
```

```
/* menu animation */

.menu {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#menu_control:checked ~ .menu {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--menu-total-height) * -1 ));
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

This works exactly as I would expect it to - it hides the menu by sliding it up by the full height of the menu when I click the menu control. The problem is that this is backwards - I want the menu to initially be hidden, then show when the control is clicked. I thus re-wrote it to move the translation to the initial (unchecked) state:

```
.menu {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--menu-total-height) * -1 ));
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#menu_control:checked ~ .menu {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

This does not work. The initial transform is applied, but it is not undone when the checked state is triggered. Is it possible to initially apply a transform, then undo it on check?

I have also attempted to use the `:not(:checked)` selector, but the behaviour is the same:

```
#menu_control:not(:checked) ~ .menu {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--menu-total-height) * -1 ));
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#menu_control:checked ~ .menu {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Did u have any luck using `transition: none;` and then using `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out`; ?

Comment: No, that simply removed the timing of the transition, but did not solve the issue. I've added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was frustratingly simply - I simply needed to add a transform to undo the initially applied translation to 0 when checked:

```
.menu {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--menu-total-height) * -1 ));
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#menu_control:checked ~ .menu {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```